# Retrofit Bearer token

Tags: android, post, retrofit2, restful-authentication

I try to receive token via POST json  {"email":"test@example.com","password":"test"}. In postman it works: 
[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6J3J.png). 
I try do the same in Android Studio. 
I create class Token:

```
   public class Token {
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    public String token;
   }
```

And class APIclient

```
    class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://mybaseurl.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

and interface APIInterface:

```
    interface APIInterface {
    @POST("/authenticate")
    Call<Token> getLoginResponse(@Body AuthenticationRequest request);
}
```

and class AuthenticationRequest:

```
    public class AuthenticationRequest {
    String email;
    String password;
}
```

In onCreate in MainActivity:

```
  apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
  authenticationRequest.email="test@example.com";
  authenticationRequest.password="test";
  getTokenResponse();
```

And here is my getTokenResponse method:

```
    private void getTokenResponse() {
    Call<Token> call2 = apiInterface.getLoginResponse(authenticationRequest);
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
            Token token = response.body();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

And this is what I see in Logcat:

```
    03-15 10:53:56.579 20734-20756/com.retrofi2test D/OkHttp: --> POST http://mybaseurl.com/authenticate http/1.1
03-15 10:53:56.579 20734-20756/com.retrofi2test D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
03-15 10:53:56.579 20734-20756/com.retrofi2test D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 46
03-15 10:53:56.579 20734-20756/com.retrofi2test D/OkHttp: {"email":"test@example.com","password":"test"}
03-15 10:53:56.579 20734-20756/com.retrofi2test D/OkHttp: --> END POST (46-byte body)
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I need to give token every time when I'd like to get information from server via GET method.
How can I receive and save token in Android code?

Comment: are you getting/sending token from header ?

Comment: in GET method I send token in header Authorization

Comment: I have posted answer. Please look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 interface APIInterface {
  @POST("/authenticate")
  Call<Token> getLoginResponse(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Body AuthenticationRequest request);
 }
```

`token` is the `Bearer token`

Answer (score 3):

you should add `application/json` to header

```
interface APIInterface {
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
@POST("/authenticate")
Call<Token> getLoginResponse(@Body AuthenticationRequest request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get access token from you need to get header from response and read values from headers.

```
Callback<User> user = new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(User user, Response response) {
        List<Header> headerList = response.getHeaders();
        //iterating list of header and printing key/value. 
        for(Header header : headerList) {
            Log.d(TAG, header.getName() + " " + header.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

After you get the value you need from header i.e. `AccessToken`, you can store that value in Storage. e.g. `SharedPreference`

So next time when you need that value you can directly get that from Storage. e.g. `SharedPreference`

Now when you pass request for any webservice either that is `GET` or `POST` or any other method. You have to pass that into header requests.

```
@GET("/tasks")
Call<List<Task>> getTasks(@Header("Content-Range") String contentRange);
```

Or If you need to pass it every time, you can directly pass that from your `Retrofit` class.

```
Request request = original.newBuilder()
        .header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
        .header("Accept", "application/vnd.yourapi.v1.full+json")
        .method(original.method(), original.body())
        .build();
```